# I copied a tkinter library code in github and now im having Indentation error

Tags: python, tkinter

So I think I accidentally deleted the **init**.py in tkinter library so I created a new one and copy the code in [GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py)
and now im having an IndentationError: unexpected indent in

```
   def __eq__(self, other):
        """Comparison for equality (==).



        Note: if the Variable's master matters to behavior

        also compare self._master == other._master

        """

        return self.__class__.__name__ == other.__class__.__name__ \

            and self._name == other._name
```

here is the whole error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mypc\eclipse-workspace\myproject\package\module.py", line 6, in 
    import tkinter as tk
  File "C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 929
    and self._name == other._name
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm just Dumb, I just need to copy it RAW that solves everything